# How to braze brass to brass

Tags: welding, brass-fitting

I'm trying to connect 2 small pieces of brass pipe together (13/32 OD) using MAP gas and I thought I could just use the bronze rods they sell at home Depot but all that did was sit on there and never melt even though the brass and it were red hot.

Had the white flux coated rod and the flux was melted just fine.

Looking online now, some pages say I need to use copper rods, or copper-phosphorous rods and others say I gotta use silver infused stainless steel rods.

Can someone explain what type of brazing rod I need to use because its not making sense to me.

Comment: What flux were you using? Were you attempting to braze without flux? Please [edit] to add these details to the question.

Comment: Solder should be satisfactory for the connection. Depending on what specific brass you have , it may melt at a lower temperature than the bronze filler rod.

Comment: Partly depends on what HD is calling """"Bronze". Any bronze should melt below 1800 F. Yellow brass may melt at 1600 F .Your flame is not hot enough.

Comment: **...asked 10 months ago.**  Real MAPP production ended in 2008.  It burned at 5300°F.  MAP-PRO gas, which is what you are likely using?  burns at 3730°F.  For reference propane at 3600°F.  So I don't "braze" brass, but if you have map-pro then that'll melt the flux but would bet not get your material hot enough to melt your brazing metal.

Answer (score 1):

You need something that melts at a lower temperature than brass. Silver solder (a type of brazing rod with 5% silver) worked for me last time.

This is brazing, so yeah it will be red hot before it melts.

Comment: silver solder is what I use for soldering my electronics, you're saying that's ok to use to solder brass connections? That seems like it would be weak

Comment: no, that's different silver solder.

Comment: ...which is why I prefer to be pedantic and refer to silver brazing as silver brazing rather than confusing things and calling it silver soldering, ever since lead-free solders with silver came out in the "actual soldering" temperature range - a *long* time ago now. Above 450°C it's brazing, below that it's soldering.

Comment: if you want to be pedantic brazing is a type of soldring.  I will admit that the term silver solder has been broken by recent developments in lead free soft solder.

Comment: Your local HVAC supplier will have the "Silver Solder" and the appropriate flux.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do it depending on the looks and strength of the joint. First is using silver solder with MAPP or Oxy-propane and flux. Second is using 10% phosphor copper brazing rod using Oxy acetylene or Propane-Oxygen. Last is strongest and best looking, Tig welding using special brass filler rod.